# SQL Query to Update multiple rows of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm in trouble right now. I'm not that good with SQL at all but for my private project I'm working with a game related database and I have to edit the `[Data]` column of the table `[_RefScrapOfPackageItem]` from the column `[Dur_U]` from the table `[_RefObjItem]`.

But the problem is I have more than 1 item which has to be updated and not every item has the same `[Dur_U]` value. For example I search for an itemcode like `ITEM_CH_TBLADE_01_C_RARE` in table `[_RefObjCommon]` and take the `[Link]` column to search for the `[ID]` of the item in table `[_RefObjItem]` (which means the Link is the ID of the item). After that I take the `[Dur_U]` from _RefObjItem table and now I want to put it into the `[_RefScrapOfPackageItem]` table in column `[Data]` where the `[RefItemCodeName]` column is the ItemCode `ITEM_CH_TBLADE_01_C_RARE` But there are a lot of different itemcodes and for each itemcode there is a own `[Data]`.

Here is my working SQL code where I can edit only 1 itemcode the same time, which will take ages to update every single item. I hope someone can help me to make the SQL query working for `LIKE` statement.

I want to "search" for every item with that ItemCode `ITEM_CH_%_01_A` (which will result in more than 1 result of course)

```
DECLARE @ItemCode VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ITEM_CH_TBLADE_01_C_RARE'
DECLARE @ItemLink INT = (SELECT Link FROM _RefObjCommon WHERE CodeName128 = @ItemCode)
DECLARE @NewData INT = (SELECT Dur_U FROM _RefObjItem WHERE ID = @ItemLink)

UPDATE _RefScrapOfPackageItem SET Data = @NewData WHERE RefItemCodeName = @ItemCode`
```

Comment: I am sorry, yes im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: can you show your data and final result in a table so we don't have to read and understand what you are trying to do. my eyes are bleeding reading your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @ItemCode varchar(256) = 'ITEM_CH_%_01_A';
update _RefScrapOfPackageItem
set Data = (
    select i.Dur_U
    from _RefObjCommon as c inner join _RefObjItem as i
        on i.ID = c.Link
    where l.CodeName128 = _RefScrapOfPackageItem.RefItemCodeName
)
where RefItemCodeName like @ItemCode;
```

Many people will have you use the SQL Server's `update...from` which is not standard SQL last I checked. This version would have the benefit or throwing an error on a non-scalar result from the subquery. Btw it's also non-standard to use aliases on the updated table.